# SSIS Redirect Invalid Dates to Error Log Table

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I'm using Visual Studio 2013/Microsoft SQL 2014.  I have a package where I import text files that contain a variety of text, numbers, and dates.  Some of the dates are invalid as shown here:

[image]

I'm trying to redirect these errors to an error log table, but the package fails outright - it does NOT redirect the specific error row.

My Data flow looks like this:

[image]

For what it's worth, the Derived Column node shown above has the following "traps" for both date fields.  These fields are used in my final mapping.  FYI:  Both of these derived date fields are NOT redirected anywhere - don't even know if this would help or how to configure this:

[image]

Anyway, the result is this:

[image]

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: I can't see pictures. But you might try this. Import as text, transform in derived column (go to configure error output and select ignore which creates nulls), conditional split nulls out on the derived column and redirect them to error flow.

Comment: It looks like these fields _are_ defined as strings.  I'm confused why the derived column conversion is not failing.  Are the invalid values literally "CreateTemporaryFile.aborting..."?

Comment: These are TSV files.  I have the text fields import as TEXT, numeric as INT or BIGINT, and dates as DATETIME.  The derived columns I created are NOT mapped to any error output.  Perhaps they should be?  Part of my confusion is why this package is not error'ing out on the first node (Flat File Source).  This should redirect the invalid date to the log Errors table.  It does NOT do this.  It passes the value down the chain and then tries to insert something into SQL that isn't a valid date.

Comment: From a flatfile source, values are imported as varchar fields. Hence dates are not being verified (for proper format or if the date actually exists- such as non-sensible dates like Feb 30th).  You could use a Data Conversion control (this is under the Common controls of the SSIS toolbox) to convert the column to a date.  Any errors from this could be directed to the error log. You currently have the error log only checking for errors at the flatfile source... but the date is not being verified at that point.

Comment: @Zorkolot I see.  I will try the Data Conversion method.  Does this mean I will have to disconnect the error output at the Flatfile Source as I have it currently established?  I assume I would then connect the error output from the Data Conversion node to the log Errors node?  Also, may I ask what is being verified at the flatfile source?  My connection manager has the field types mapped as I want them (matches the field types in the resultant SQL table).  I assumed that if an invalid value hit at that level it would redirect it.

Comment: EDIT:  Apologies, @Zorkolot, I think you already answered my last sentence/question where you said "dates are not being verified" at the Flatfile Source).  But I find it interesting though as I DO get records redirected at that level as my Log Errors table contains redirected rows from other imports that I've done.  Looks like most/all the redirected rows I get are because there was truncation or some kind of data overflow.

Comment: @Craig Not sure what is going on at the flatfile.  There is the Common Language Datatype datetime that is outside the range of SQL Server's datetime.  That could be the case here, where it is only checking the format and not the range of the dates. I would try disconnecting from the flatfile and doing this from the Data Conversion.